# Associating an object with existing objects according to some property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

A belongs to B. From the create method of the controller of object A, how can I look through all of objects B according to some property they have and get the id of some matching object B? The ultimate goal is to assign A to the proper B object with a b_id foreign key.

This is what I currently have, although it only creates new objects and fails to find old ones to associate to. I end up with a bunch of hosts by the same name but with different ids:

```
        #assign line to host
          begin
            #attempt to assign line to existing host
            line.host = host.where(:name => line.hostname).first
          rescue
            #create new host
            line.host = Host.new({:name => line.hostname})
          end
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. What do you need beyond `a.b = B.where(...).first` ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung that sounds like what I need. I've never used that before, and was unaware of it. I'm including my attempt at what you've provided me, although so far it's only creating new objects and not finding old ones to associate to.

Comment: Usin rescue like that is a bad idea - you've no idea what you're rescuing (eg it could be a nomethoderror due to a typo). The code that you've written doesn't raise when no object is found - it just returns nil, so the rescue does nothing useful - just check the return value (but see also `first_or_create`)

Comment: @FrederickCheung Thanks! The error message after that was useful enough to find my problem. Lesson learned.

Answer (score -1):

```
        #assign line to host
          line.host = Host.where(:name => line.hostname).first_or_create
```